# How to update the view if props value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## class TicketTabDetails ,This class responsible for display actual content of the side menu item when clicked

```
class TicketTabDetails extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  render () {
    console.log(this.props.ticketItem);
    let detailedContent = (
        <Section pad="medium">
          {this.props.ticketItem}
        </Section>     
      );
    return detailedContent;
  }
}
```

## class TicketTabData ,This class responsible for both tabs sidemenu and menu data section

```
class TicketTabData extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFetchTabData = this.onFetchTabData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      ticketdata : ''
    }
  }
  onFetchTabData(tabdata) {
    this.setState({ ticketdata: tabdata });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Split flex="right">
        <Sidebar colorIndex="light-2">
          <BuildSideMenu menuitem={this.props.branch} onFetchTabData = {this.onFetchTabData}/>
        </Sidebar>
        <Article scrollable={true}>
            <TicketTabDetails ticketItem={this.state.ticketdata}/>
        </Article>
      </Split>
    );
  }
}
```

Here class TicketTabDetails is not able to return the updated ticketItem that was passed as property, how to update the view if the property value changes?

Comment: Assign the value of props to the state.

Comment: @RahulDagli , I have now assigned it to state(Please see the updated code above) but its now giving an error says "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, data}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Box`"

Comment: Props in state is considered to be an anti-pattern. Avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: @RahulDagli , your answer was correct, that was my mistake that i have directly populated an object instead of its property and was giving error, thanks for the help!!!..